# Calculus 1 - Differential Equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> $$\pi  \left(6 h(t)-h(t)^2\right) h'(t)=-\frac{h^{1/2}(t)}{\sqrt{3}},h(0)=3$$

Im supposed to solve this differential equation when $h(0) = 3$, and im not sure how it's supposed to be solved. And im not sure what kind of differential equation it is.

So i would really appriciate if i could get some help solving this equation.

Comment: It's separable. You can write it as $g(y) y'=c$ .

Comment: I was using $y$ for $h(t)$.

Comment: basically: $\pi(6h-h^2)h' = k\sqrt(h)$, so $h' = \frac{k\sqrt{h}}{\pi(6h-h^2)}$, so $h' = \frac{k}{\pi(6\sqrt{h}-h^{3/2})}$

Answer (score 1):

Set $y=h(t)$ you get
$$dx=\sqrt{3} \pi  (y-6) \sqrt{y}\,dy$$